# Mockito not mocking private variables using @Spy

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I am attempting to mock a private instance variable `listOfStrings` using Mockito's `@Spy` annotation.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyObjectTest {

  @InjectMocks
  MyObject myObject;
  @Spy
  List<String> listOfStrings;

  @Before
  public void before() {
    myObject = new MyObject();
  }

  @Test
  public void testCallListOfStrings() {
    Mockito.doReturn(new ArrayList().stream()).when(listOfStrings).stream();
    myObject.callListOfStrings();
  }
}
```

and

```
public class MyObject {

  private List<String> listOfStrings;

  public void callListOfStrings() {
    listOfStrings.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

It does not appear to be mocking the instance variable, throwing a `NullPointerException`, obviously.

Comment: Try with java Reflection I have added a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myObject = new MyObject();` - this is the root of the problem. `Mockito` instantiates the mock for you, but you're replacing the mock with your own `myObject` instance, what leads to NPE (obviously, the `listOfStrings` is null in your newly instantiated object).

That how it should work:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyObjectTest {

    // Don't do this with List! 
    // Type 'List' is an interface and it cannot be spied on.
    @Spy
    private ArrayList<String> listOfStrings;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyObject myObject;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        listOfStrings.addAll(List.of("test", "test2"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallListOfStrings() {
        Mockito.doReturn(new ArrayList().stream()).when(listOfStrings).stream();
        myObject.callListOfStrings();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test
test2
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot @InjectMocks created a new instance of the object before each test.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try With Java Reflection. I think you need to avoid the null pointer exception.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyObjectTest {

    @InjectMocks
    MyObject myObject;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        myObject = new MyObject();
    }

    @Test
    public void testCallListOfStrings() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

        Field list = myObject.getClass().getDeclaredField("listOfStrings");
        list.setAccessible(true); // Suppress Java language access checking
        list.set(myObject,new ArrayList<>());
        myObject.callListOfStrings();
    }
}
```

You can assign a value for the private variable

> listOfStrings

That will avoid the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `Mockito.initMocks(this)` inside `before()`. Also, you don't need to initialize `myObject` because `mockito` will initialize it for you.

I would also like to note that your test really isn't doing anything, because you're not asserting or verifying anything, you're just calling the `MyObject.call ListOfString()` method.